# Find the correct Cassandra.yaml file

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am new to Cassandra, I am having issue with identifying the exact cassandra.yaml file as my search on linux shows 3 different files in different location. Can anyone please tell me how to locate the correct '**cassandra.yaml**' file used by my running Cassandra.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Cassandra's db!

The cassandra.yaml's file is (normally) in `/etc/cassandra/conf` .

You can see in the picture below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In our case it was different. Is there any Cqlsh query unlike in mysql use to do like 'select @@datadir;' for viewing the data directory path.

Comment: I'm not sure if we are talking about the same thing. The Cassandra.yaml file and CQLSH are differents. The CQLSH is the terminal like mysql terminal and you can execute your queries And Cassandra.yaml file is the db's configuration. If you could, please give us more details in your question.

Answer (score 0):

On my ubuntu 20.04 release, cassandra.yaml is found at `/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml`